# Delphi with multichannel soundcard ( ASIO )

Tags: delphi, audio, delphi-xe3, asio

I haven't been able to find any info at all about Delphi and any example with using multichannel external soundcards, preferable via ASIO protocol.

I did found some ASIO information, but they're not in any help, since all of the info is provided for different usage.

What I'd need to achieve is:

-Have my App recognize the external USB/FW  soundcard, via the device's driver, which is already installed;
-List available output channels (input channels are not needed for the purpouse, although having info about those wouldn't hurt...)
-Use desired output channels so that I can send some data/audio to each of them separately controlled

Main goal is to send different levels of audio, which could be either noise, hum, fixed frequency modulated wave or anything..., to each of the output channels. The need for such is, because  I need to show data, that is received via UDP to the app itself,  on the audio VU-meters of the soundcard; I'm not receiving actual audio signal, but just data of the audio levels of each channel. That level needs to be translated to an actual audio level and then sent to the soundcard;

Any help would be appreciated!

Best,

M.

---

EDIT:

The direct question:

How to access external multichannel soundcard via device's driver installed, and send different audio streams to each of the available channels?

Are there any useful examples of using ASIO and multichannel external soundcards in Delphi app?

Comment: This is a broad statement of goals and desirable properties. You should ask a very specific question.

Comment: delphi bindings for ASIO: http://www.axiworld.be/asio.html. You should look at the sample host in the download. As for hijacking the soundcard's VU meters I think you are going to be out of luck.

Comment: It's not about hijacking the VU-meters. That's exactly the point why I need to access all of the output channels -> to send the audio stream from the app to the soundcard, and with that achieve that the soundcard will show values on it's vu-meters. I'm basically trying to show remote audio levels on local soundcard without the real audio stream; to achieve that, I still need to send some audio stream to the soundcard;

Answer (score 0):

I'd pull all the sources of the [DelphiAsioVST](http://delphiasiovst.sourceforge.net/) project.
It contains tens of examples in there. There are VCL components to talk to ASIO drivers, so there must be something useful there for you.

I've never used those with more than 2 channels myself, and I'm not on a PC that has it installed right now, but it would amaze me if you can't find a solution after installing DelphiAsioVST.

I've seen some more lightweight (and more low level) wrappers, but I never used them for anything useful yet. Could be something to look for as well.